# Manifest Execution failed

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

This is the message.

Comment: This isn't a question...   Please read the guidelines on posting questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Change **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1** to **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file,

Select `Merged Manifest` from bottom left corner [image: View image]

On Right side, AndroidStudio will suggest you what is the issue in your project, and how it can be resolved.

Hope it helps!