# failed : app:processDebugMainfest in android

Tags: android

Merging Errors:

> Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value
>   value=(26.0.1) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-35 is also present at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0). Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-24:15 to override.

Comment: Please consider adding some details, like what steps you took to get this error.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198992/manifest-execution-failed/45199145#45199145

Comment: Search on google `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the error report. Read it.

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-24:15 to override.

Add `tools:replace="android:value`" in your manifest file.

check this question
[Manifest merger failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095703/manifest-merger-failed-error). It is explained very clear

Comment: i also did it but same problem

Comment: Did u add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` name space in manifest

Comment: yes i added also

Comment: use the same version of android library in your gradle